# Dots show on Volume material

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, volumetrics

So I've done the atmosphere, but the Volume material has given it loads of dots. I assume this is the resolution of the Volume light but is there a way to get rid of them without bumping up the resolution to over 100,000?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decreasing the *Step size* in the material settings:

[image]

Note that this will increase render time.

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the step size then reduce the number of attempts to speed up render time

I use a step size of 0.04 and attempts at 100 on my planet render

Answer (score -1):

Check out Andrew Price's article on eliminating fireflies.  He lists 7 settings that reduce their appearance.
[Link to Article](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/#.U9uiPWP1v8s)

If that doesn't work, try adding a *Despeckle* node to your compositor pipeline.