# Noise in Blender Internal Smoke Sim?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a background using [this](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/335-tutorial-a-cool-looking-inkdrop-in-blender.htm) tutorial and I've been doing some renders, and they've been going well. (if only baking didn't take so long... )
Anyway, I have a problem, as you can see in this image,

[image: this]

the smoke has weird noise within the transparent parts of it, does anyone know how to fix this? I upped the resolution, so that's not the problem... I'm not too experienced with Internal so I don't know if noise is normal.
Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Try decreasing the *step size* in the volume material.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14612/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decrease the *Step Size* in *Properties > Materials > Integration > Step Calculation*:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've got one more question, as you can see in this video, I've got two additional problems. One being that for some reason it shakes like crazy, I think the domain may be moving...? I checked it and there are no keyframe problems, have you seen this problem before? The other one is, why does the smoke get cut off at the beginning of the video and is only a full "flow" when it reaches the other side?

https://vid.me/aNI5

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gogonimago For a separate problem it's best to ask a new question. That said, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Whoops, I will make sure to next time, thanks! Here is the .blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34147